# cannot install phpmyadmin in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: java, php, oracle, phpmyadmin, ubuntu-14.04

I have installed phpmyadmin in ubuntu before. But now it seems like not possible. I am stuck with some **oracle-java6-installer** failure.

I have run `sudo apt-get update` and then a `sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin` as usual. But the following error occurs and the installation fails.

> Preparing to unpack .../phpmyadmin_4%3a4.0.10-1_all.deb ...
>   Unpacking phpmyadmin (4:4.0.10-1) ...
>   Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.13-1) ...
>   Processing triggers for doc-base (0.10.5) ...
>   Processing 1 added doc-base file...
>   Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
>   Setting up oracle-java6-installer (6u45-0~webupd8~8) ...
>   Downloading Oracle Java 6...
>   --2017-10-25 09:13:20--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/6u45-b06/jdk-6u45-linux-x64.bin
>   Resolving download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)... 184.25.108.41, 184.25.108.17
>   Connecting to download.oracle.com 
> (download.oracle.com)|184.25.108.41|:80... connected.
>   HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
>   Location: https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/6u45-b06/jdk-6u45-linux-x64.bin [following]
>   --2017-10-25 09:13:20--  https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/6u45-b06/jdk-6u45-linux-x64.bin
>   Resolving edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)... 23.65.97.122, 2600:140f:b:184::2d3e, 2600:140f:b:183::2d3e
>   Connecting to edelivery.oracle.com 
> (edelivery.oracle.com)|23.65.97.122|:443... connected.
>   HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
>   Location: http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/6u45-b06/jdk-6u45-linux-x64.bin?AuthParam=1508903146_f5ba776a72e71785aa3526c9fb49f911 [following]
>   --2017-10-25 09:13:23--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/6u45-b06/jdk-6u45-linux-x64.bin?AuthParam=1508903146_f5ba776a72e71785aa3526c9fb49f911
>   Connecting to download.oracle.com 
> (download.oracle.com)|184.25.108.41|:80... connected.
>   HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
>   2017-10-25 09:13:26 ERROR 404: Not Found.
>   
>   download failed
>   Oracle JDK 6 is NOT installed.
>   dpkg: error processing package oracle-java6-installer (--configure):
>    subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1

is there any other way around??

Answer (score 0):

Is this is a new server that you are setting up? If so- you'll need a complete LAMP stack set up before installing PHP (**L**inux/**A**pache/**M**ySQL and **P**HP). If you need directions on that, you can find them [here.](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-16-04)

You'll also need to make sure you are installing all of this as non-root user with sudo access. [See why here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/initial-server-setup-with-ubuntu-16-04) :

> The root user is the administrative user in a Linux environment that has very broad privileges. Because of the heightened privileges of the root account, you are actually discouraged from using it on a regular basis. This is because part of the power inherent with the root account is the ability to make very destructive changes, even by accident.

Let me know if this helps.